# Remove past dates and next months dates from the current month displaying

Tags: javascript, date, coldfusion-10, mura

I am trying to figure out a way to remove past dates, future months dates, and both past and future dates events and only display current month dates and their events.

I am new to javascript and I am not able to determine how to add the following piece of code.

```
    eventRender: function(event, element, view)
{
   if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { return false; }
}
```

into a code that took me a while to figure out but was able to use certain sections of fullcalendar to create another calendar:

```
    <cffunction name="FullCalendar">

    <cfscript>

        var calendarid = $.getbean('content').loadby(title='Regal Events').getcontentid();


    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>           
                <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
                 <div id="UpcomingCal" class="calendarResize">
                 </div>
         <script>

         mura.loader()
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",{media:'all'})
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-custom.css",{media:'all'})
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",{media:'print'})
            .loadjs(
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/gcal.js",
                function(){
                     $('##UpcomingCal').fullCalendar({

                         eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: '#variables.$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/proxy.cfc?calendarid=#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                , type: 'POST'
                                , data: {
                                    method: 'getFullCalendarItems'
                                    , calendarid: '#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                    , siteid: '#variables.$.content('siteid')#'
                                    , categoryid: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('categoryid'))#'
                                    , tag: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('tag'))#'
                                }
                                <!---, color: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].background#'
                                , textColor: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].text#'--->
                                , error: function() {
                                    $('##mura-calendar-error').show();
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    })
                }

               )
         </script>


        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

**Update:** I learned I need to use weekMode to hide both past months and future months days and the events that belong to them. However, not sure how to implement it to the code I have